# How do I allow my server to ftp to itself?

Tags: iptables, firewall, wordpress, sftp, rhel6

I'm on RHEL6 and I'm trying to do an auto update on wordpress but the ftp and sftp connections fail. I suspect it's at least testing the connection from within the server which is not allowed by my firewall.

I added this line to /etc/sysconfig/iptables, but it still didn't work. Any ideas?

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All same-host connections will be done through `lo` (loopback) interface, which is not restricted by default and allowed by putting line to the top of rules:

```
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

Wordpress auto update usually works without FTP access, if not - there must be a very very tight security limit on the webserver/php. Usually wordpress is checking disk space and permissions with some ugly functions (AFAI remember, there was something related to inode checks (WEIRD)).

> For Automatic Update to work, at least two criteria must be satisfied:
>
> (a) file ownership: all of your WordPress files must be owned by the
>   user under which your web server executes. In other words, the owner
>   of your WordPress files must match the user under which your web
>   server executes. The web server user (named "apache", "web", "www",
>   "nobody", or some such) is not necessarily the owner of your WordPress
>   files. Typically, WordPress files are owned by the ftp user which
>   uploaded the original files. If there is no match between the owner of
>   your WordPress files and the user under which your web server
>   executes, you will receive a dialog box asking for "connection
>   information", and you will find that no matter what you enter in that
>   dialog box, you won't be able to update automatically.
>
> (b) file permissions: all of your WordPress files must be either owner
>   writable by, or group writable by, the user under which your Apache
>   server executes.
>
> On shared hosts, WordPress files should specifically NOT be owned by
>   the web server. If more then one user owns different files in the
>   install (because of edits made by deleting and re-uploading of files
>   via different accounts, for example), the file permissions need to be
>   group writable (for example, 775 and 664 rather then the default 755
>   and 644). File permissions (in general) should be adjusted as
>   appropriate for the server environment (the shared host RackSpace
>   CloudSites for example recommends 700 and 600 for a single ftp user,
>   or 770 and 660 for multiple ftp users). See the file permission
>   section for more (some files and folders require stricter
>   permissions).

(c) http://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Automatic_Update

Check for permissions etc

If you still want to do it with FTP - be sure it's listening to local address too `netstat -anp|grep 21`.

SFTP? Really? You don't want to do this. Believe me.

Comment: 9/10 linux issues end up being permissions somewhere it seems

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track, but there's some Wordpress magic you need to do here. Speaking from experience, the FTPS still tries to use port 21, not SSH (port 22). I don't remember the exact procedure I followed to enable SSH updating, but a different version of it is here: http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/tips-articles/quick-tip-upgrade-your-wordpress-site-via-ssh/. See the 'Method 2' section. If that doesn't get you where you need to be, a Google search on "update wordpress ssh" should give you some useful URLS - apologies that I can't find the one I used.

Comment: I did have to add the :22 port to my hostname to get it to use sftp.